# HTC Desire 526 stuck "Proccessing" after factory reset

Tags: htc-desire

I just recently factory reset my htc desire 526 and when I turned it back on, this happened[image]

and then this happened

[image]

I've tried going into recovery mode and rebooting from there, i've also reset from the recovery screen, but every time it leads up to that point.
its currently been stuck there for like 30-40 mins,

Help appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I'm just curious, how do you get the good quality screenshots when the phone is stuck?

Comment: i mean its not frozen, i just take screenshots holding the power button and the volume down button at the same time(i think at the same time)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turn phone off remove the sim card and start your phone again.

Answer (score 0):

Turning it off taking out the battery and the sim card replacing the battery and turning it back on got my phone past that page. Rekia87 was right.